# Price dropdown menu not working Apple Developer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Im submitting my app to the Appstore and I want to make it free. But the price tier menu is greyed out and not selectable. I've tried it with different browsers (safari & google chrome) however still no result. Does anyone know what's the problem

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue from last couple of day, did you get any solution ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not Apple Developer support. Please open a ticket with them: https://developer.apple.com/support/

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani The issue was resolved couple days ago, its working now

Comment: @KwonMin-sik Was not working yesterday, for me this got resolved today :)